# Withdrawal of coins to Trezor did not happen, Where are my coins?

Tags: trezor

I set-up Trezor yesterday and withdrew coins from my exchange to store in the Trezor. I entered the address and conifrmed.
However, an hour later, Trezor said Network error. It was unable to receive the coins.
The address I entered is also not showing up on Trezor today.
How do I get my coins?

Answer (score 1):

If you used the correct address, you have received that money already even if your Trezor doesn't yet know about them.

If the public blockchain (not the unrelated business who use that name) shows your address has the money, you already have it. The public blockchain is the only true record.

You won't be able to spend that money until you fix whatever problem is causing that reported network error (or until you use your safe backup copy of the seed phrase or private-key in another wallet)